# Top not showing processes using CPU resources

Tags: central-processing-unit, top

I have this output from `top` for the top 10 processes sorted by CPU usage descending:

```
top - 11:19:58 up  1:46,  2 users,  load average: 3.22, 3.48, 3.34
Tasks:  66 total,   5 running,  61 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 77.5%us, 14.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  7.0%id,  0.9%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,   299012k used,   749564k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 7982 kenilwo   17   0  160m  53m  23m R  4.2  5.2   0:00.63 php
 7984 kenilwo   17   0  158m  51m  23m R  2.5  5.1   0:00.38 php
32245 mysql     15   0  214m  25m 4924 S  0.9  2.5   0:38.58 mysqld
32592 root      15   0 90724  26m  592 S  0.1  2.6   0:03.85 memcached
 1491 nobody    15   0 72336 3572 1656 S  0.1  0.3   0:00.43 httpd
 1495 nobody    15   0 72336 3560 1644 S  0.1  0.3   0:00.41 httpd
 1503 nobody    15   0 72200 3556 1656 S  0.1  0.3   0:00.43 httpd
 5992 root      15   0 12732 1264  956 R  0.1  0.1   0:01.80 top
32425 nobody    15   0 72192 3676 1784 S  0.1  0.4   0:00.47 httpd
32427 nobody    15   0 72332 3704 1784 S  0.1  0.4   0:00.44 httpd
```

What is odd is that it reports that 77.5% of the CPU resources are being used by user processes, yet, when I look at the top 10 processes, their usage is less than 10% (other processes on the system do not have CPU usage).

What's going on? What is purloining my CPU resources?

Comment: Heh, nice load average. Somethings throttling your stuff. What distro are you running? Can you grab `htop` utility from your package manager?

Comment: @Tim, can you post your suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it as correct? `htop` showed me some procs that top was hiding; I think that these were system processes running from the `/usr/sbin` directory.

Comment: There you go sir. Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the utility `htop` if it is available in your package manager. Top doesn't always show everything depending on the distro you are using based on my past experiences.

Answer (score 1):

When presented with a similar issue recently I had a look at the rest of the processes. As it happened, none of them were using a lot of the CPU but all of them *combined* amounted to far more than just the top few.

Comment: I've seen this myself - a lot of dinky processes using 0.1% - 0.5% can add up pretty quick (and given your load average I wonder how many `httpd` processes you have dong little bursts of CPU activity...)

Answer (score -2):

Press H (uppercase) to show threads.